Cross-entropy loss with varying number of classes
Is there a standard/efficient way in Pytorch to handle cross-entropy loss for a classification problem where the number of classes depends on the sample?
Example:
In a batch of size 3, I have:
logits1 = [0.2, 0.2, 0.6],      labels1 = [0, 0, 1]
logits2 = [0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4], labels2 = [1, 0, 0, 0]
logits3 = [0.2, 0.8],           labels3 = [1, 0]

I am looking for the right way to compute cross_entropy_loss(logits,labels) on this batch.

Cross entropy loss is used when a single output class is being predicted. When you say the number of classes depends on the sample, I assume you mean a situation where the number of logits is different for each sample is different, but we are still in a cross entropy situation where each sample has one correct class.
In this case you can simply pad the samples with -inf which will be ignored in the cross entropy loss calculation.
# start with our sequences
sequences = [
    [0.2, 0.2, 0.6],
    [0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4],
    [0.2, 0.8]
]
sequences = [torch.tensor(i) for i in sequences]

# represent labels as class int values
# this is required for pytorch's crossentropyloss
labels = torch.tensor([2, 0, 0]).long()

# pack sequences into a square batch
# fill padding values with `-inf`
padding_value = float('-inf')
sequences_padded = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence(sequences, batch_first=True, padding_value=padding_value)

# create `CrossEntropyLoss` with `reduction='none'`
# this makes the loss return the value for each input (ie no averaging) 
# so we can compare values
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='none')

# compute loss on individual sequences without padding
l1 = torch.stack([loss(sequences[i], labels[i]) for i in range(labels.shape[0])])

# compute loss on padded sequences
l2 = loss(sequences_padded, labels)

# check values match
assert torch.allclose(l1, l2)

This works because cross entropy computes exp(i) for all values in the input, and exp(-inf) evals to 0. Because of this, the padding values have no impact on the output loss.
